# Make a table row fade in as its class changes?

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have a button that is clicked to reveal a table row:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("label.deathzone-toggle").click(function() {
    $("tr.deathzone").toggleClass("show");
  });
});
```

```css
tr.deathzone td {
  display: none;
}

tr.deathzone.show td {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label class="custom-control-label deathzone-toggle" for="customSwitches">Show Deathzone Inducements</label>
```

That all works fine but I'm trying to fade in/out the rows, I've tried fadeIn("slow");but it's not working. I also tried adding `transition:opacity 1.5s ease;` to the css and that does not work either? Bit stuck!!

Comment: You can use the keyframes from this to make it work https://stackoverflow.com/a/9334132/2943218

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use .fadeIn("slow") while changing the display attribute of the "tr" to none and not its "td"s.

```
tr.deathzone {
 display: none;
}
```

2 examples:

https://jsfiddle.net/somidmm/03tn69kx/

```
function test() {$("#2").fadeToggle("slow");}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/somidmm/ad6bjh8c/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("label.deathzone-toggle").click(function() {
  $("tr.deathzone").fadeToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

Comment: yes but as with the other answer when you toggle again the row stays there.

Comment: using .fadeToggle() should work.

Comment: unfortunately not.

Comment: Actually sorry, yes this does work! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't transition the display property as you are hoping to do but you could instead transition the opacity which would give the same effect?!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("label.deathzone-toggle").click(function() {
    $("tr.deathzone").toggleClass("show");
  });
});
```

```css
tr.deathzone td {
  display: table-cell;
  opacity:0;
  background:white;
  transition:ease-in-out all 250ms;
}

tr.deathzone.show td {
  opacity:1;
  display: table-cell;
  background:pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<label class="custom-control-label deathzone-toggle" for="customSwitches">Show Deathzone Inducements</label>

<table>
  <tr class='deathzone'>
    <td>.... some content</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I thought about that but If I did that the rows would still take up blank space on the page.

Comment: as I say, I don't think you can transition the display property so perhaps add `height:0` and transition that also

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
tr.deathzone td {
  display: none;
}

tr.deathzone.show td {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

use

```
  tr.deathzone td {
      opacity: 0;
      visibility: hidden;
      height: 0;
      transition: opacity 0.5s ease;

    }
   tr.deathzone.show td{
      opacity: 1;
      visibility: visible;
      height: auto;
    }
```

and same jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("label.deathzone-toggle").click(function() {
    $("tr.deathzone").toggleClass("show");
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't work.